# Multiple Ui dialogs on the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've more than one link on my page each of them opens a different UI dialog,

**This is the dialog code:**

```
$('#photo-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    width: 500,
    height:460,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            // do some action 
            $(this).dialog('close'); // Close the Confirmation Box
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            //if the User Clicks the button "cancel"
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

// if a user clicks on the "delete" image
$('a.album').click(function(e) {
    $('#photo-form').dialog('open');
});
```

My problem is that once I open the first dialog and then finish the action I need to do on it and then close it by clicking save or cancel,

**First:** when I click the link of the second dialog it didn't open unless I reload the page and I don't want to do this.

**Second:** when I try to open the same dialog again it opens the previous instant, I need to reset it.

When I tried to use `$(this).dialog('destroy')` instead if `$(this).dialog('close')` for closing the first dialog, I can open the second dialog but when I clicked the link of the first dialog I couldn't open it again.

Comment: Are you saying you have two different dialogs, a "photo-form" and another, or that you have several delegated links that open the same dialog?

Comment: I have several delegated links that opens twwo different dialogs

Answer (score 0):

I cant figure out what you mean exactly.

Try this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Doinkmeister/gZBgR/

There are 2 dialog boxes and both open on click.

Please also give your html code as the problem might be there.

*$(this).dialog('close');* Should do the trick.

is all of your code inside the document.ready()

try adding all of your code inside a

```
$(function(){
    $('#photo-form').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal:true,
        width: 500,
        height:460,
        buttons: {
           "Save": function() {
               // do some action 
               $(this).dialog('close'); // Close the Confirmation Box
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                //if the User Clicks the button "cancel"
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $('a.album').click(function(e) {
        $('#photo-form').dialog('open');
    });
});
```